# Is JSX/TSX markup as a constant sent by value or by reference?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I have a constant in a separate file `EmptyNode.tsx`:

```
export const EmptyNode = <></>
```

Which I use to return an empty node when I don't want to show any content.

Example:

```
...
render() {
    if(!this.props.data) {
        return EmptyNode 
    }
}
...
```

Here is a more advanced example:

```
...
render() {
    const myContent = EmptyNode

    if(this.props.data) {
        myContent = <MyComponent data={this.props.data} />
    }

    return myContent
}
...
```

Thus, if it's sent by reference, I will break all the markup in other places if I once change the value of it.

If it's sent by value then I can safely use it as it is.

Here, if I assign `<MyComponent/>` to `myContent`, will it change value of `EmptyNode` for all other code that consumes it or not?

Comment: little bit out of the question, but isnt EmptyNode useless? you can just return null insteed

Comment: Agree, but it's more for illustration. In reality I can put some more content instead of just `<></>`, e.g. `<div>No data</div>`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a purely pass-by-value language. It doesn't have the concept of a reference to a variable that would be required for pass-by-reference semantics.

In your `render`, when you do this:

```
const myContent = EmptyNode
```

The **value** in your `EmptyNode` constant is copied into `myContent`, after which `EmptyNode` and `myContent` are **not linked in any way**. They both have the same value in them (which is a reference to an object), but there is no link between the constant and the variable.

Later, when you do:

```
myContent = <MyComponent data={this.props.data} />
```

you're creating an object and assigning that reference to `myContent`. `EmptyNode` is completely unaffected.

It's worth noting that after `const myContent = EmptyNode`, when both `myContent` and `EmptyNode` have the same value in them and thus both refer to the same object, if you modify *that object* via `myContent` (`myContent.foo = "bar"` or similar), then naturally that change is visible via `EmptyNode`, since they both refer to the same object. But that's a completely different thing than assigning to `myContent`, the variable. Since that can confuse people a bit, here's an example:

**Case 1**: Modifying the value in the variable:

```js
let a = {value: 1};
console.log(a.value); // 1
let b = a;
console.log(b.value); // 1

// At this point, we have something like this in memory:
//                      
// a:Ref11345−−−−−+    
//                |     
//                |     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                +−−−−>|  Object  |
//                |     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                |     | value: 1 |
// b:Ref11345−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//
// `a` and `b` have the same value (Ref11345) in them. (We never see
// the actual value of an object reference, Ref11345 is just notional.)

b = {value: 2};

// At this point, we have something like this in memory:
//
//                      +−−−−−−−−−−+
// a:Ref11345−−−−−−−−−−>|  Object  |
//                      +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                      | value: 1 |
//                      +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                      
//                      +−−−−−−−−−−+
// b:Ref68214−−−−−−−−−−>|  Object  |
//                      +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                      | value: 2 |
//                      +−−−−−−−−−−+
//
// `a` and `b` refer to different objects.

console.log(a.value); // 1 - the value on the original object
console.log(b.value); // 2 - the value on the new object
```

**Case 2**: Modifying the object the variable points to

```js
let a = {value: 3};
let b = a;

// At this point, we have something like this in memory (again):
//                      
// a:Ref52413−−−−−+    
//                |     
//                |     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                +−−−−>|  Object  |
//                |     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                |     | value: 3 |
// b:Ref52413−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//
// `a` and `b` have the same value (Ref52413) in them, they both
// refer to the same object.

console.log(a.value); // 3
console.log(b.value); // 3
// This changes the state of the object
b.value = 4;

// Now, we have something like this in memory:
//                      
// a:Ref52413−−−−−+    
//                |     
//                |     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                +−−−−>|  Object  |
//                |     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//                |     | value: 4 |
// b:Ref52413−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−+
//
// `a` and `b` still have the same value (Ref52413) in them, so
// they both still refer to the same object.

console.log(a.value); // 4 - the value on the original object (updated)
console.log(b.value); // 4 - same
```

---

Side note: The "reference" in pass-by-reference is specifically about references to variables/parameters. The "reference" in "object reference" is a different usage of the word "reference." This is sometimes confusing to people. :-) But it's just the same general word being used in two different ways.

Comment: This is a little misleading in OP's case, since a React element object (as constructed by JSX or `React.createElement()`) is a plain object that is mutable.

Comment: @AKX - It doesn't matter that the object is mutable. In fact, it doesn't even matter than it's an object. Assigning a new value to the `myContent` variable doesn't, in any way, affect the value in `EmptyNode` nor modify the object it refers to. But maybe I should note that assigning to a *property* on that object (rather than to the variable) would be problematic, though people don't usually assign to properties on React elements.

Comment: @AKX - I've added some diagrams to help make the distinction. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely share the JSX element wherever you need it, so long as you don't mutate it.

Mutating elements is not supported and has... peculiar effects, it seems. I have no idea what's going on here, really. :)

```js
const thing = <div></div>;

const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(1);
  thing.props.children = Array(counter).fill('Hello!').join(' ');  // don't do this IRL
  thing.key = counter; // force update
  return <div>{thing} <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Increment</button></div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```